# AWK - execute string as command?

Tags: awk

This command prints:

```
$ echo "123456789" | awk '{ print substr ($1,1,4) }'
1234
```

Is it possible to execute a string as command? For example, this command:

```
echo "123456789" | awk '{a="substr"; print a ($1,1,4) }'
```

Result:

```
$ echo "123456789" | awk '{a="substr"; print a ($1,1,4) }'
awk: {a="substr"; print a ($1,1,4) }
awk:                               ^ syntax error
```

**EDIT:**

```
$ cat tst.awk 
function my_substr(x,y,z) { return substr(x,y,z) }

{ a="my_substr"; print @a($1,1,4) }
bolek@bolek-desktop:~/Pulpit$ echo "123456789" | gawk -f tst.awk
gawk: tst.awk:3: { a="my_substr"; print @a($1,1,4) }
gawk: tst.awk:3:                        ^ nieprawidłowy znak '@' w wyrażeniu
bolek@bolek-desktop:~/Pulpit$
```

Comment: Its a pretty common thing to want to define a generic function to, say, iterate over all the elements of an array and perform some operation X on each element where X varies by invocation and being able to assign a function name to X lets you avoid writing a series of "if"s or a switch statement (gawk).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call user-defined functions via variables in GNU awk using indirect function calls, see http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Indirect-Calls

```
$ cat tst.awk
function foo() { print "foo() called" }
function bar() { print "bar() called" }

BEGIN {
   the_func = "foo"
   @the_func()

   the_func = "bar"
   @the_func()
}
$ gawk -f tst.awk
foo() called
bar() called
```

Unfortunately due to internal implementation issues, if you want to call builtin functions that way then you need to write a wrapper for each:

```
$ cat tst.awk
function my_substr(x,y,z) { return substr(x,y,z) }

{ a="my_substr"; print @a($1,1,4) }
$ echo "123456789" | gawk -f tst.awk
1234
```

Comment: Do you know of anything similar for POSIX awk?

Comment: No, there's nothing like it for POSIX awk.

Comment: @Ed Morton, The last example does not work. You can check it again? Thank you.

Comment: No need to check it again as I copy/pasted the command working the first time. If you tell us in what way it "does not work" for you, maybe we can help.

Comment: You're probably using an old version of gawk. What does gawk --version tell you? I'm using 4.0.0.

Comment: I use version ->`$ gawk --version
GNU Awk 3.1.7
Copyright (C) 1989, 1991-2009 Free Software Foundation.`

Comment: OK, then get a more recent version.

Comment: In version `GNU Awk 4.0.1` works fine. Why not work on `GNU Awk 3.1.7` and `mawk`?

Comment: Indirect function calls are a fairly recent GNU awk extension, apparently more recent than gawk 3.1.7. You won't find indirect function calls in any awk other than gawk, except possibly tawk which is no longer available/supported. mawk has minimal functionality compared to even POSIX awks, it's only benefit is that it will often run faster than other awks.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think it is possible to do that in awk directly, but you can get a similar effect by using the shell. Recall that the awk program is given as a string, and strings are concatenated in the shell just by writing them next to one another. Thus, you can do this:

```
a=substr
echo "123456789" | awk '{ print '"$a"'($1, 1, 4) }'
```

resulting in `1234`.