# Evaluate a string as a command in gawk

Tags: linux, unix, awk, gawk

I need to use a set of rules that are maintained in a separate file to determine if documents that are being processed in a gawk script are valid.  The rule file contains lines like the following:

`record[3] > 5 && record[35] ~ /Boiler/`

Having read the rules file into an array I now want to go through each line of the array to check if the criteria is true, for each input document.  Something like the following, where rule_array[i] is evaluated using the rule above.

```
for (i=1;i<=rule_count;i++){
    if (rule_array[i]){
        flag="T"
    }
}
```

How can I treat the strings in rule_array like commands to use in the if statement.  The if statement should be equivalent to:

`if (record[3] > “5.0” && record[35] ~ /Boiler/){`

Having scoured the internet it seems easy in shell script but this must be run in gawk because it is just a small part of an enormous script.  Using awk, the closest thing seems to be the following, but I don’t think that would work here as it’s not a command.

[AWK - execute string as command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13743163/awk-execute-string-as-command)

UPDATE:

To simplify the problem, how can I get the following to evaluate.  I want the logic in "logic" to be used, rather than the test: is "logic" not empty.

`awk 'BEGIN{var=2;logic="var==5";if(logic){print "TRUE"}}'`

Thanks,

Ger

Comment: So `rule_array[i]` contains "record[3] > “5.0” && record[35] ~ /Boiler/" and you want to "`eval`" it inside the `if`? I don't think you can do that, although I'm happy to be proven wrong. Perhaps there's a better way round the problem though, what exactly are you trying to do here?

Comment: Why not make the separate file a gawk script instead? Then you can run it in advance for each file to check if they are valid..

Comment: That's exactly it Tom.  I want to supply a list of conditions that will be used by an awk script.  They need to be supplied separately so that the main script isn't constantly being edited.

Comment: Håkon, I am already in an awk script where the input files are read into arrays (the record[] array) to be checked against set criteria.  A separate awk script wn't work becasue I may need to check different lines of the array at the same time e.g. the if condition might be "if line1 of the input file is equal to line 9", so I can't process the input line by line.

Comment: Using `-v` option of awk, it's possible to pass external variables like your rules to an awk internal variable. But the `record` array I'm still unable to pass from the outside.

Comment: Hi Marcel.  Using the -v option leaves the same problem.  The string passed in is still a string weather it's stored in an array or a variable.  Besides, I would rather avoid the way this is called becasue it's an enormous script (around 4000 lines) and is called as part of a complicated batch process every night.  The fewer scripts I need to modify the better.

Comment: Ok, so what does that `record` array represent? (Note that it might be a good idea to put a `@` sign in front of the names you are replying to, like @Geraint, then the user will be notified about your comment, see http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-reply )

Comment: Ah, thanks @Håkon Hægland.  The record array represents the stuff that needs checking.  I have over simplified the example, probably to the point of confusion so in the real example the script is run on a file containing data arranged in structures blocks of many lines.  The rules would apply to spcific parts of the blocks e.g. lines beginning with "ADDR" would contain the address.  The third field on the ADDR line would contain the house Number.  Perhaps a check would be to make sure that it contains the digits 0123456789.  The entire data block is read into an array before processing begins.

Comment: So to keep it easy, how would I get line to work that I have marked as updated above?

Comment: It is a bash script with an awk script inside it?

Comment: @Geraint is it? a bash script with your awk script inside it?

Comment: Hi @Marcel.  No, it is a standalone awk script that performs multiple actions on data blocks it receives as input.  I can't modify the way the script runs because of the number of actions it performs.

Answer (score -1):

The following perl script will generate the correct awk script for you:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use File::Slurp qw(read_file);

my $awkcode=read_file('a.awk');

open(my $fh,"<","rules.txt");

while (<$fh>) {
   chomp;
   my ($key, $val)=/(\S+)(.*)$/;
   $awkcode=~s/\Q$key\E/$val/mg;
}
close($fh);

print $awkcode;
```

Given awk script `a.awk`:

```
BEGIN{
    var=2
    if(logic1){
        print "TRUE1"
    }
    if(logic2){
        print "TRUE2"
    }
}
```

and a rules file `rules.txt`:

```
logic1 var==5
logic2 var==2 || var==5
```

The output from the script is a new awk file:

```
BEGIN{
    var=2
    if( var==5){
        print "TRUE1"
    }
    if( var==2 || var==5){
        print "TRUE2"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Håkon Hægland. So it's not possible to treat a string as the condition and the only way of doing this is to generate a new script?  That's not possible here as this is part of a long and complicated batch job.  The current awk script is already 4000 lines long so I'm not going to get approval to regenrate it on a daily basis (too much risk).  I thik I'll need to rethink this.

Comment: @Geraint Yes maybe best to transfer the whole script to an object oriented perl script (or python). Then I think it will be simpler to work with in the future.. Awk is best suited for small projects I think.